# using .as extenion files in flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

Hai 
  Am very new to flex application development.Am using flex builder 4 and i need to call .as file from mxml file.please help to do this with sample code (Demo).And how to use java file to get and set data.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It would be better if you ask the java question separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, simply do:

```
import myasfile
```

Or if it's coming from a different directory, you could simply specify your directory on the dot notation, such as:

```
import renderers.myrenderer
```

As per using the Java file, you will need to use remote objects to connect to your Java class. There's a really nice video introduction [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_java_integration.html)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using something like this

```
<mx:Script source="includes/IncludedFile.as"/>
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/usingas_4.html

Comment: I don't think he's trying to import.  He's just trying to 'call'

Comment: If it is a AS class, yes can create and object and call (or call a static method). If it is just an AS file, he has to import it before calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just instantiating or calling an actionscript class, do something like this:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
   import yourpackage.SomeClass

   private function someFunction():void
   {
      SomeClass.someStaticFunction();
      // or
      new SomeClass().someNonStaticFunction();
   }
]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Also, if you class extends `IMXMLObject` you can include it directly in the mxml withing the declarations tag like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
   <someNamespace:YourClass someProperty="true" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

Hope that helps.  You should really read up on mxml and look at examples.  I have [several on my blog](http://www.michelboudreau.com).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import MyAsFile.as //if your file is inculded in .src folder
import path/MyAsFile.as //if in other folder
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Comment: when you import, you don't include the extension and you don't use '/'